# how to delay a signal for several cycles in vhdl

Tags: delay, vhdl

How to delay signal for a given number of cycles in VHDL?
Number of cycles is given as a generic.

Any other options instead of

```
process(CLK) is
begin
  if rising_edge(CLK) then
    a_q <= a;
    a_q_q <= a_q;
    a_q_q_q <= a_q_q;
    -- etc
  end if;
end process;
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an 1-d array (let's call it `a_store`) of the appropriate type of signal with the length of the array related to the number of cycles.  This may mean you have to create a new type for the array unless there's already a vector type you can use: eg. `std_logic_vector` or `integer_vector` (the latter is standard only in VHDL-2008).

Then shuffle the array along each tick:

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  a_store <= a_store(store'high-1 downto 0) & a;
  a_out <= a_store(a_store'high);
end if;
```

Comment: let me try it, but it seems great