# Delay a signal in vhdl

Tags: delay, vhdl

I would like to delay a signal several cycles in vhdl, but I have problems using [how to delay a signal for several cycles in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918133/how-to-delay-a-signal-for-several-cycles-in-vhdl/)

Wouldn't I need a registered signal? I mean, something like:

---

```
a_store and a_store_registered would be std_logic_vector(cycles_delayed-1 downto 0)
```

---

```
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      a_store_registered <= a_store;
    end if;
end process;    
a_out <= a_store_registered(cycles_delayed-1);

process(a_store_registered, a)
begin    
      a_store <= a_store_registered(size-2 downto 0) & a;
end process;
```

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution you link to *is* a registered signal - the very act of writing to a signal inside a process with a `rising_edge(clk)` qualifier creates registers.

An even simpler implementation of a delay-line can be had in one line of code (+ another one if you want to copy the high bit to an output)

```
a_store <= (a_store(a_store'high-1 downto 0) & a) when rising_edge(clk);
a_out <= a_store(a_store'high);
```

Not sure why I didn't mention this in my answer to the linked question!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are approaching the problem as you are; there is no need for a second process here. What is wrong with the method suggested in the linked question?

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
  a_store <= a_store(store'high-1 downto 0) & a;
  a_out <= a_store(a_store'high);
end if;
```

In this case your input is `a` and your output is `a_out`. If you want to make the delay longer, increase the size of `a_store` by resizing the signal declaration.

If you want to access the intermediate signal for other reasons, you could do this:

```
a_store <= a_store_registered(cycles_delayed-2 downto 0) & a;
process(clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk) then
      a_store_registered <= a_store;
    end if;
end process;    
a_out <= a_store_registered(cycles_delayed-1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that you can use the `foo'delayed(N ns)` attribute or `foo <= sig after N ns` in simulations.