# How does this VHDL code work?

Tags: vhdl

I would have just put a comment in the sourced post below but I don't have that privilege yet so I thought I might just ask a question so that I can get some clarification.

[how to delay a signal for several cycles in vhdl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918133/how-to-delay-a-signal-for-several-cycles-in-vhdl?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Basically I need to implement 2 clock cycle delay to this process located in the behavioral of my VHDL project (the code for which is shown below):

```
  process(font_address(0), font_address(1), font_address(2), font_address(3),font_address(4), font_address(5), font_address(6), font_address(7),vga_hcount(0), vga_hcount(1),vga_hcount(2),CLK)

begin




--if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
  -- a_store <= a_store(1 downto 0) & a;
  -- a_out <= a_store(1 downto 0);
 --end if;

if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
case vga_hcount(2 downto 0) is
when "000" => font_bit <= font_data(7);
when "001" => font_bit <= font_data(6);
when "010" => font_bit <= font_data(5);
when "011" => font_bit <= font_data(4);
when "100" => font_bit <= font_data(3);
when "101" => font_bit <= font_data(2);
when "110" => font_bit <= font_data(1);
when "111" => font_bit <= font_data(0);
when others => font_bit <= font_data(0);
end case;
end if;



end process;
```

As you can see I have made it such that it takes a single clock cycle delay before the signal assignments in the process are made as provided by the if statement wrapped around the signal assignments but I cannot seem to create a synthesize-able 2 clock pulse delay despite reading the answered question linked above

When I comment the if statement wrapped around the case and uncomment the following block of code

```
 if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
 a_store <= a_store(1 downto 0) & a;
 a_out <= a_store(1 downto 0);
 end if;
```

Which was taken from the link given at the beginning of this question I get the following error:

[Synth 8-690] width mismatch in assignment; target has 2 bits, source has 3 bits ["U:/Computer organisation lab/vga/vga_prac.vhd":304]

the target being referred to in this error message is the a_store vector and the source is the concatenation of a_store and a.

This is after I assigned logic 1 to a and created a_store and a_out as std_logic_vectors with 2 elements (as I want a delay of two clock cycles). I think the reason I am getting this error is because even after reading over this question for hours I still can't seem to understand how it actually is supposed to generate a 2 clock cycle delay.

I thought at first it might be that a 1 bit gets iterated through the a_store vector until the MSB is one and then this vector is applied to a_out but looking at the fact that it is in all in an if statement I cannot see how these two lines of code would even execute more than once. If this were even true I would have to have some test to make sure that a_out has a 1 in its MSB.

Usually I would have moved on but after extensive searching I couldn't find a simpler solution than this despite the fact I don't fully understand how it is supposed to work.

If somebody could clarify this or suggest a modification to my program which will generate the required delay that would be great.

Thanks in advance,

Simon.

Comment: There are many unnecessary names in the process sensitivity list. Only `CLK` is required.

Comment: The code you claim to have copied/pasted from the other question is in fact different.

Comment: Martin's answer to your linked question shows `a_store <= a_store(store'high-1 downto 0) & a;` which gives the right answer. In a descending range (downto) 'high gives the index value of the left bound.  For an array subtype with two elements 1 downto 0 that would be a_store(0 downto 0) an array value with one element. Your problem is you didn't implement Martin's answer faithfully. You could also provide an [MCVe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so the declarations are visible. Also `font_bit <= font_data(to_integer(unsigned(not vga_hcount(2 downto 0))));` an 8 input multiplexer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the first code is not that efficient, and could be reduced to

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
[...]

process(CLK)
begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        font_bit <= font_data(7 - to_integer(unsigned(vga_hcount(2 downto 0))));
    end if;
end process;
```

For the second part, the error says everything. You say `a_store` has 2 bits (or "elements" as you call it), then you can imagine that `a_store(1 downto 0) & a` is two bits of `a_store` + 1 bit of `a` = 3 bits. You cannot assign 3 bits to 2 bits. How would that fit? Same problem for assigning `a_out`: How can 2 bits fit into 1 bit?

Thus:

```
if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
    a_store <= a_store(0) & a;
    a_out <= a_store(1);
end if;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, when I get back to the lab I will make this change and see if it works properly.

Comment: This works only I had to assign a_store(1 downto 0) to a_out and not what you have done here. Thanks though.

Comment: @burton01 As you did not provide the full code, that can be true. I just suggested the code for a normal two clock delay.